# Matlab displays binary number in engineering format

Tags: string, matlab, binary, double, precision

In Matlab, I need to convert a decimal number into the binary and the converted binary number into the double number.

for example:

```
a= 3151;
b=dec2bin(a);
b=str2double(b);
```

I need the answer b=110001001111 but instead of it, 1.1000e+11 will appear.

I need the lsb of the binary number and the functions below will accept only double numbers not binaries as strings.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Are you sure the _functions below_ take `double` type as input. A `double` only holds one single floating point value, it cannot represent a series of different bits. Which `lsb', least significant _bit_ or _byte_?. What do you do with it after ? Convert it back to a floating point ? or you want it as an array of bits ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to change matlab formatting with `format short`, `format long` etc. if you want to alter the way that numbers are displayed. I think you can use `format long g` which will work the way you want, though I never used it before.

```
format long g;
b
```

> b =
>
> 110001001111

Another way to deal with this is to tell matlab to specifically print the variable a certain way, like this:

```
format short;
sprintf('%i', b)
```

> ans =
>
> 110001001111